# Bootstrap Navbar does not work when I resize the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a collapsible Bootstrap navbar. The toggle does not appear when i resize the browser. I tried changing the codes around to what I have seen on other forums like grouping my logo and buttons, however that messes up the layout. I would greatly appreciate any help, Thank you!

```css
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .collapse {
      position: fixed;
      top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
      bottom: 0;
      left: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      overflow-y: auto;
      visibility: hidden;
      background-color: #343a40;
      transition: visibility .3s ease-in, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in, visibility .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .collapse.open {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%)
    }
  }
```

````html
<div class=".container-fluid">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="./index.html">
                    <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="sultry silk logo">
                </a>
               <button class="navbar-toggle collapse p-0 border-0" type="button" data-           toggle="collapse"  data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                            
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
                   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item active">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html" class="buttons">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./Icons.html" class="buttons">Icons</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./tech.html" class="buttons">Technology</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="./sustain.html" class="buttons">Sustainability</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./culture.html" class="buttons">Politics & Culture</a>
                     </li>
                </ul>
                            
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
</div>
</nav>```
````

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, why are you specifying media queries? Bootstrap handles resizing on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code snippet.

Firstly, on your `nav-link` classes, you're using two class declarations:

`<a class="nav-link" href="./culture.html" class="buttons">Politics & Culture</a>`

This will cause HTML errors and will probably effect your styles in CSS; simply fix this by placing your `buttons` class next to `nav-link`

`<a class="nav-link buttons" href="./culture.html">Politics & Culture</a>`

---

Next, your HTML for the `button` tag will cause errors with Bootstrap.

- Your using class `navbar-toggle`, change this to `navbar-toggler`
- There is a large space on your data-toggle `data-           toggle="collapse"` close this up.
- `collapse` is already a bootstrap class; this needs to be removed.

---

Working Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="./index.html">
    <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="sultry silk logo">
  </a>

  
  <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./Icons.html">Icons</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./tech.html">Technology</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./sustain.html">Sustainability</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./culture.html">Politics & Culture</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Have a look at the **[W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)**; this tool will analyse your website and alert you of any HTML errors it finds.

Comment: As you pointed out, there are a couple of small HTML errors that could make debugging hard for newcomers. Maybe you can add a reference to W3C validator? the https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you! Getting rid of the css media queries and changing the redundancy in the classes resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

.collapse is a Bootstrap class. If one of your specified properties interferes with one that is defined in the .collaps class by Bootstrap, it could cause errors. 
1. Try either defining your own collapse class and name it differently, or
2. Use !important to override the Bootstrap values.

Number 1 is recommended.